# Is there a way to stack divs on top of each other using flexbox syntax?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Flexbox issue. Hopefully someone can help :)

I'm trying to build a deck of cards made of divs and stack them over each other like you would using position:absolute.

**Is there any way to get divs to overlay each other in the same space using flexbox?**

Comment: I think flexbox is the wrong technology for this, what code do you have so far?

Comment: flexbox wasn't really designed for this - positioning was. Is there a reason you aren't able to use positioning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43919067/3597276

Answer (score 23):

One way to get it is to set a negative margin. A deck of cards using it:

```css
.deck {
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
    height: 100px;
    width: 60px;
    flex: 100px 1 0;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="deck">
<div class="card">1</div>    
<div class="card">2</div>    
<div class="card">3</div>    
<div class="card">4</div>    
<div class="card">5</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this with a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to have some code from you and more information, but I think it's possible.

If you want to do it solitaire way:

Just add overflow hidden to cards on top and `max-height` let's say `20px`.

Last one should have no `max-height` and `overflow:auto`.

However thing that you are doing it's probably easier to do without flexbox. Flexbox can be used with `position:abosolute` too. They are different attributes. Give some examples of what are you trying to accomplish maybe I will be able to help.