# React JS : using `flexbox` to implement one div over another

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

React JS, implement one div over another using `flexbox` layout only.

- Is that possible to impl the layout in the picture below without using `position:'absolute'`, only using `flexbox` layout.
- Or there are more elegant solution in React JS ?

[image]

Comment: This isn't related to react at all, really.

Comment: We don't write up code here at SO, so post your own effort and we'll see how we can help

Comment: Flexbox is not designed for overlapping. But CSS Grid is. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43919067/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't other ways I can think of except of `calc()`

```html
<div style="display: flex; height: 200px; align-items: center;">
    <div style="flex: 0 0 100%; height: 100%; background-color: grey;"></div>
    <div style="width: 30%; height: 60%; margin-left: calc(-50% - (30% / 2)); background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

The support for `calc()` http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc is pretty good now

Note that 30% in `margin-left` is the width of the overlay element, if the element's width is let say 30px, change the 30% in `margin-left` to 30px

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean, do you mean overlapping neighbour element like this? `<div style="display: flex;"><div class="grey"></div><div class="red"></div></div>`

Comment: To my extent there isn't a way to do it unless you use the trick of `calc()`, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `align-self: center;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to set the box in center.