# Is it possible to make grid element take 1.5 space in container?

Tags: css, css-grid

So I found this layout and I wanted to make it using `display: grid`

[image]

So far I came up with this

```
.header__grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 380px 500px 500px;
    grid-template-rows: 305px 305px;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "sweets food  meat"
      "sweets text fruits"
}

.header__grid-sweets {
    grid-area: sweets;
}

.header__grid-food {
    grid-area: food;
}

.header__grid-meat {
    grid-area: meat;
}

.header__grid-text {
    grid-area: text
}

.header__grid-fruits {
    grid-area: fruits;
}
```

And it looks like this

[image]

The problem is the the last block, with fruits, should take more than one cell in grid and the block to its left should take less. I guess it is because I'm setting with of columns with `grid-template-columns`

So the question is is there a way to work around this?

All the help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
grid-template-columns: 380px 500px 500px;
```

Try something like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(100, 10px)
```

Then used [line-based placement](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement) to created grid areas across those tracks.

[Here's an example from another answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43919551/3597276)