# Alignment of item using flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-position

Following is the code which is working fine with `position: relative` and `position: absolute`. However I am trying to achieve similar effect using `Flexbox` and though the item is adjusted in the center but it is not overlapping like the one achieved using position. Let me know how can I achieve the similar effect using `Flexbox`.

Code -

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; }
.green { background: #2a9d8f; }
.blue { background: #333366; }

/* Position CSS */
.position-container { position: relative; }
.box1, .box2 { position: absolute; }
.box1 { width: 60px; height: 60px; left: 120px; top: 120px; }
.box2 { width: 40px; height: 40px; left: 130px; top: 130px; }

/* Flexbox CSS */
.flex-container { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
.box3 { width: 60px; height: 60px; }
.box4 { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="container position-container">
    <div class="box1 green"></div>
    <div class="box2 blue"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container flex-container">
    <div class="box3 green"></div>
    <div class="box4 blue"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919067/make-flex-items-overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **negative margins** to adjust the overlapping. Add `margin-left: -50px;` to `box4` to achieve the desired output.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; }
.green { background: #2a9d8f; }
.blue { background: #333366; }

/* Position CSS */
.position-container { position: relative; }
.box1, .box2 { position: absolute; }
.box1 { width: 60px; height: 60px; left: 120px; top: 120px; }
.box2 { width: 40px; height: 40px; left: 130px; top: 130px; }

/* Flexbox CSS */
.flex-container { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
.box3 { width: 60px; height: 60px; }
.box4 { width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-left: -50px; }
```

```html
<div class="container position-container">
    <div class="box1 green"></div>
    <div class="box2 blue"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container flex-container">
    <div class="box3 green"></div>
    <div class="box4 blue"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change HTML and put the blue box inside the green one. Then,
add css for green box:
`.box3 { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }`

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container { width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; }
.green { background: #2a9d8f; }
.blue { background: #333366; }

/* Position CSS */
.position-container { position: relative; }
.box1, .box2 { position: absolute; }
.box1 { width: 60px; height: 60px; left: 120px; top: 120px; }
.box2 { width: 40px; height: 40px; left: 130px; top: 130px; }

/* Flexbox CSS */
.flex-container { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
.box3 { width: 60px; height: 60px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
.box4 { width: 40px; height: 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="container position-container">
    <div class="box1 green"></div>
    <div class="box2 blue"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container flex-container">
    <div class="box3 green">
      <div class="box4 blue"></div>      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the same effect but using flexbox only, I don't think you can do that but you need to use position with flexbox like code below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.green {
  background: #2a9d8f;
}
.blue {
  background: #333366;
}

/* Position CSS */
.position-container {
  position: relative;
}
.box1,
.box2 {
  position: absolute;
}
.box1 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 120px;
  top: 120px;
}
.box2 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 130px;
  top: 130px;
}

/* Flexbox CSS */
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box3 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}
.box4 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container position-container">
  <div class="box1 green"></div>
  <div class="box2 blue"></div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="container flex-container">
  <div class="box3 green"></div>
  <div class="box4 blue"></div>
</div>
```