# Is there a possible way to use Bulma CSS to create an overlapping image?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

Is there a possible way to use Bulma CSS to create an overlapping image?

Is there a possible way to use Bulma CSS to create an overlapping image?
[click link to see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtK6k.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since Bulma uses flexbox, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919067/make-flex-items-overlap