# How can i make flex items overlap in a column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

The goal is to have stacks of playing cards stacked vertically, a [solitaire stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwSN7.png) is a good mental image (little bit of the previous card poking out the top with the bottom most card fully visible)

I am using  instead of  for the .cards but they seem to match the snipper behaviour 1-1 from what i've seen.

For horizontal stacking i copied the top answer to this question: [Make flex items overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919067/make-flex-items-overlap?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 35em;
}

.cardWrapper {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/  /*using width shows better overlap*/
  min-width: 3.5em;
}

.cardWrapper:last-child, .cardWrapper:hover {
    /*overflow: visible;*/ 
    min-width: 10.5em; /*full width + 2*padding */
}

.card {
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: solid #666 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0.25em;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 1 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 2 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 3 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 4 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 5 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is great now i just need to convert it to a vertical stack.

Here is what i tried:
In 'flex' the default major axis is horizontal, so I hoped specifying column  would sort everything out but alas.
**Expected Result**: neat stacking

**actual Result**: full Height cards in a column

Other things i have tried

- maybe the wrappers need to be columns aswell -> add in  display: flex;  flex-direction: column;   justify-content: center;    align-items: center;  -> this only moves the column to centre of screen.
- since "flex-direction: column;" was specified for .card in original maybe revert it to default of row-> no change as far as i can tell.

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*change main axis to vertical, but now no stacking*/
  align-content: center;
  max-width: 35em;
}

.cardWrapper {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/  /*using width shows better overlap*/
  min-height: 2em;
}

.cardWrapper:last-child, .cardWrapper:hover {
    /*overflow: visible;*/ 
    min-height: 6.5em; /* full height + 2*padding*/
}

.card {
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: solid #666 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0.25em;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 1 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 2 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 3 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 4 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 5 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost figured it out. You change the `min-width` to `min-height` but forgot to change `max-width` to `max-height`. Just change that and it work with your current code.

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*change main axis to vertical, but now no stacking*/
  align-content: center;
  max-height: 22em;
}

.cardWrapper {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/  /*using width shows better overlap*/
  min-height: 2em;
}

.cardWrapper:last-child, .cardWrapper:hover {
    /*overflow: visible;*/ 
    min-height: 6.5em; /* full height + 2*padding*/
}

.card {
    width: 10em;
    min-width: 10em;
    height: 6em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    border: solid #666 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 0.25em;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 1 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 2 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 3 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 4 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <div class="card">card 5 blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set max-height of card and change the style as below.

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  max-height: 35em;
  max-width: 20em;
}

.cardWrapper {
  min-height: 3.5em;
}

.cardWrapper:last-child,
.cardWrapper:hover {
  min-height: 10.5em;
}

.card {
  height: 10em;
  min-height: 10em;
  height: 6em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  border: solid #666 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0.25em;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```